# How to pass some custom cookie parameters in fastcgi

Tags: c, fastcgi

I have written a server in fcgi and C and I need to add some custome parameter after I printed some String to request.out.
to be clear this is my sample code:

```
while (1) 
{
    rc = FCGX_Accept_r(&request);
    if (rc < 0)
        break;
    FCGX_FPrintF(request.out,
        "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
        "\r\n");
    //the html page content
    FCGX_FPrintF(request.out,
        "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\">"
        "<input type=\"text\" name=\"num\">"
        "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"click\" name=\"submit\">"
        "</form>"       
        );
    .
    .
    .

    //and somewhere like here I need to add a cookie parameter
    FCGX_FPrintF(request.out,
    "set-cookie:myParam=myValue\r\n"
    "\r\n");
    .
    .
    .
    .
    FCGX_Finish_r(&request);
}
```

But this ends up printing right to the page. How can I put it to the start of the buffer?

Comment: can you write it before the `Content-Type` to get it in the header blob?

Comment: In this server I parse an HTML page or a CSP page that wherever in the page Session_start could be called. how could I set sessionid after I put some string to request.out stream.  I can put the page content in a string and then call FCGX_Print(...) but I was looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP protocol has the following schema for requests and responses:

```
<header 1>\r\n
<header 2>\r\n
...
<header n>\r\n
\r\n
<body>
```

So any header that you need to send must be sent before the empty line that separates the headers and body section of the response.

In your case, you need to write the `set-cookie` header either before, or immediately after `Content-Type`, otherwise the browser will interpret it as part of the response body. Also, I'd recommend following the casing convention:

```
FCGX_FPrintF(request.out,
    "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
    "Set-Cookie: myParam=myValue\r\n"
    "\r\n");
```

Comment: n this server I parse an HTML page or a CSP page that wherever in the page Session_start could be called. how could I set sessionid after I put some string to request.out stream. I can put the page content in a string and then call FCGX_Print(...) but I was looking for a better solution.

Comment: You cannot send the sessionid (another header) after you began sending the body, so yes, in your particular case you need to parse the HTML page before sending the headers. What's your flow with the parsing of the HTML page, maybe that one can be improved.

Comment: Yes you are right.If I want to parse CSP page that contains HTML,CSS,JS and C code , how can I do that?

Comment: An alternative would be to parse the page twice: the first time you extract the data needed for the sessionid, the second time would be what you have now.